# Disable animation of UITableView with NSFetchedResultsController when many rows are being changed

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

In my UIView I've got a UITableView (UITV) which is controlled by an NSFetchedResultsController (NSFRC). The UIView is inside a UINavigationController.

When the view is about to be loaded/displayed I start some background activities which fetch data from a remote server (JSON) and parse into Core Data.

The NSFRC is being called when the parsing is done and the threaded NSManagedObjectContext have been merged into the main context.

The problem is that sometimes many rows are being inserted to Core Data at once, a lot of table cells are being added and there is quite a delay from that the actual fetching and parsing is done, until the rows are being displayed.

**Now I wonder if anyone knows of any solution to, for example:**

- hook up a spinner to some "fetched results controller inserted all its rows for this time" (or something) notification/delegate call to at least tell the user that "something is going to show up soon"?

Or might the best solution simply be to not initialize the NSFRC until the background fetching and processing is completed?

Thanks!

Comment: What's actually taking the most time here? Is it the server request or are you trying to fetch a huge number items of items out of Core Data? If its the fetch that is slowing you down, you can modify your fetch request to only fetch as many items as will be needed on screen initially and then lazily load the rest on demand.

Comment: The NSFetchedResultsController's fetchRequest's batch size is currently set to 20, but when more than 20 objects are being inserted, more these objects are also loaded into memory for a short period of time. Do you know of any way to alter the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate functions to only insert rows that will be visible (or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you may want to look into the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods, with documentation available here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

There are delegate methods available for pre changes with `controllerWillChangeContent:`, post changes with `controllerDidChangeContent` and during changes with `didChangeSection:` and `didChangeObject`.

I hope it helps!
Rog

Comment: I've implemented these delegate functions, but in these I haven't found any way to determine if there is 100 objects changed (inserted/updated/deleted) or just one.

Comment: it shouldn't matter. Say if you want to have an activity indicator of any sort so the user knows that something is being loaded, you can create and add it to the view on `controllerWillChangeContent:` and then notify that the processing has been completed on `controllerDidChangeContent`, remove it from the view and let the user continue. Makes sense?